# jQuery + Get Parents of list of elements

Tags: jquery, css

I have a web page that includes a table. In that table, I have rows of cells that our generated on the server. For that reason, I have limited access to the elements.

In each row is a cell that contains a div. I want to get the parent cell of each div and add a class to it. In an attempt to do that,

I have the following [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/humotrj0/48/). When the `selectAll` function gets called, I'm trying to grab all of the `div` elements with a class of `description`.

Then, I want to add the `selected` class to all of the `td` elements that host a `description`.

I know `$('.description');` gives me all of the divs. I could loop through these and grab the `parent`. But, I was wondering if there was a better way to do this with selectors. If so, how?

```js
function selectAll() {
  var divs = $('.description');
}
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');

.description {
  background-color:#eee;
}

.selected {
  padding:2rem;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>      
        <th>Count</th>        
        <th>Description</th>      
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>
          <div class="description">
            Simple description
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>
          <div class="description">
            Simple description
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td style="padding:0;">
          <div class="description">
            Some more text.
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  
  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="selectAll();">
    Select All
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Comment: [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Comment: A quick search on Google would have given you the answer

Comment: [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
$('.description').closest('td').addClass('selected')
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/humotrj0/49/

---

```js
function selectAll() {
  $('.description').closest('td').addClass('selected');
}
```

```css
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 .description {
  background-color: #eee;
}
.selected {
  padding: 2rem;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Count</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>
          <div class="description">
            Simple description
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>
          <div class="description">
            Simple description
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td style="padding:0;">
          <div class="description">
            Some more text.
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="selectAll();">
    Select All
  </button>
</div>
```